# Frequent long loads (~9 seconds)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

Our production server has started acting weird on all our hosted websites.

It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 server running IIS and ~15 asp.net 3.5 websites. I've tested half of the websites hosted by this server and all of them have the same symptoms. It seems very random when it occurs but at least once every minute a page will take ~9 seconds to load. Thats the only pattern i've found so far. So my first guess was that something made the apps recycle so i tried some logging in "Application_End()" and got the following:

```
MSG:
Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b9b284ca\4eb9bb86\hash\hash.web
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

STACK
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdown()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.OnWebHashFileChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

This message has only occured twice though and now im not able to get it at all anymore. So im still pretty much clueless on what is going on.

Has anyone else experienced this?